# R: Johansen test for two variables

Tags: cointegration

I am trying to replicate work from [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17520843.2019.1599980?scroll=top&needAccess=true), specifically examination of the rationality of inflation and inflation expectations when both series are non-stationary I(1). I need to apply Johansen cointegration method to test whether series of inflation and inflation expectation are cointegrated with a vector (1,-1). However, bh5lrtest does not work no matter how I set 'r' argument (I believe it should be equal to 1). Where is the problem? Is there any alternative regarding the code?

```
data <- data.frame(inf_cpm_s, gt_inf_s) # inflation and its expectations
jotest <- urca::ca.jo(data, type = "trace", K = 2, ecdet = "const", spec = "transitory")
summary(jotest)
my_vector <- c(1, -1)
summary(bh5lrtest(jotest, H = my_vector, r = 1))
```

When r = 1, I get following error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': 
Row number of 'H' is unequal to VAR order.
```

However, for any r greater or equal to 2, I get this:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': 
Count of cointegrating relationships is out of allowable range.
```

Answer (score 0):

For this test, you need r>1, because the number of columns in your H matrix must be smaller than r. In other words, given that you only have two variables in your system, this test isn't applicable, because you cannot obtain more than one cointegrating vector.

For example, if you have a system of three variables and run ca.jo with a restricted constant and obtain r=2 (two cointegrating vectors), you can run bh5lrtest to see whether or not your first cointegrating vector is for instance (1,-1,-1,0). What bh5lrtest does (at least in my opinion) is estimate your other cointegrating vectors given your H matrix, which has a row number equal to the number of your variables and a column number equal to the number of known cointegrating vectors.

Also, please note that the row number of your H matrix must be one more than the number of your variables if you include a constant in your ca.jo specification.